# Why use the complex conjugate for Fourier spectra division?

Tags: matlab, fft, complex-numbers

I saw several codes written where Fourier spectra are divided with the complex conjugate like this:

```
af = fftn(double(img1));
bf = fftn(double(img2));
cp = af .* conj(bf) ./ abs(af .* conj(bf));
```

in [this script](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26417-extphasecorrelation/content/ExtPhaseCorrelation.m) among others.

Is this related to handling complex division? Reading the documentation about the `./` operator, it is stated that it handles complex numbers. So is this wrong?:

```
af./bf
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expressions `af./bf` and `af.*conj(bf)./abs(bf).^2` are completely equivalent in MATLAB, if that's what you're asking. There is no clear connection, however, between that question and the example you've shown. `abs(bf).^2` does not appear in the denominator in your example.

The only reason `conj()` is being used in the code you've shown is because it is the Fourier dual of time inversion

I.e., f(t)<-->F(k) implies f(-t)<--->conj(F(k)), for real-valued time signals f(t).

This has a specific application to [time delay analysis using phase correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_correlation#Method).

Comment: There is no reason you cannot element-wise divide Fourier spectra or any other array of complex numbers. The code example you've shown is in no way reflective of such a restriction.

Comment: Good explanation and link. +1 Phase correlation has a very natural application to image registration.

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite this expression avoiding the conjugation as

```
(af./bf)./abs(af./bf).
```

However, the given form of the expression has the advantage that you can desingularize the division by adding a small epsilon to the denominator,

```
(af.*conj(bf))./(1e-40+abs(af.*conj(bf)))
```

Comment: Couldn't you likewise desingularize with (af.*conj(bf))./(1e-40+abs(af.*bf))  ?

Comment: Yes, since abs(a*b)=abs(a)*abs(b)=abs(a*conj(b)). What to chose is a question of readability versus number of operations. Some may prefer to have the same notation in both places. Or separate the operations for higher efficiency as in `cp=af.*conj(bf); cp=cp./(1e-40+abs(cp))`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following equivalent (within about `1e-15`) code:

```
cpX = exp(1i*(angle(af)-angle(bf)));
```

You can compute the normalized cross power spectrum as you have shown with the complex conjugate (`cp = af .* conj(bf) ./ abs(af .* conj(bf))`) or by explicitly subtracting the phase as above.

Considering that [the FFT of a shifted impulse is a *complex exponential*](http://www.thefouriertransform.com/pairs/impulse.php), the `cpX` equation should give some insight into how "phase correlation" allows you to find a translation between two images. The *location of the peak* in the inverse FFT gives the translation.